# pushviewcontroller is not work in xcode6

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller

The below code is work in ipad,but not in iphone.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreAppsViewController"];

UINavigationController *navgiate = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:navgiate animated:YES];
```

i cannot able to load `MoreApsviewController` by instatinating. View Controller is not pushing Please help me how to do it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller (is your view that you are trying to access embedded in a navigation controller?) as your access point? And have you named your Navigation View `MoreAppsViewController` or your destination VC? These are just two small steps to get out of the way before trying something else.

Comment: You can't push a navigation controller onto another navigation controller.

Comment: Perhaps you mean self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];?

Answer (score 1):

If your container is a navigation controller, you can simply intilize a VC and push it like this;

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreAppsViewController"];
    //No need to create a nav controller here
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If you want to add another navigation controller you can present it or add as child VC, but you can't push another navigationVC.

Comment: The above concept is work to ipad,but not to iphone.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 steps should be checked.

1. If the View Controller you are trying to access is embedded in a Navigation controller you are correct in referencing the correct view, otherwise, change `UINavigationController *navgiate` to `UIViewController * navigate` (OR UITableViewController * navigate if it is a Table View).
2. Check your referencing of View Controllers. If you have the name `(UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreAppsViewController"];` I will assume that you have named your View Controller `MoreAppsViewController`. You need to name ***and reference*** the UINavigationController as it is the point of reference.

This is the result for View Controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreAppsViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This is the result for Navigation Controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
//You need to name your Navigation Controller "MoreAppsViewController" for this to work
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreAppsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```